# Trying to build a sample Red5 Secure project but it fails because of some dependencies

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors, spring-security, red5

I found this tutorial: http://blog.infrared5.com/2012/05/red5-authentication/ and tried to build it. I use netbeans and created a freeform project on the "server" directory. Everything went well but the build faild becuse it couldn't download some Spring framework libraries (security acl, config and core). I found them manually, downloaded the same version it needed (3.0.7). This error went away but changed to some Java compile-time errors. :-(

For example:

> Compiling 6 source files to /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/www/WEB-INF/classes
>   /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/src/org/red5/demo/auth/AggregatedUserDetailsService.java:29: package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails does not exist
>   import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
>   /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/src/org/red5/demo/auth/AggregatedUserDetailsService.java:30: package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails does not exist
>   import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
>   /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/src/org/red5/demo/auth/AggregatedUserDetailsService.java:31: package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails does not exist
>   import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
>   /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/src/org/red5/demo/auth/AggregatedUserDetailsService.java:38: cannot find symbol
>   symbol: class UserDetailsService
>   public class AggregatedUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService, ApplicationContextAware {
>   /Users/ist1/Downloads/red5-auth/server/src/org/red5/demo/auth/AggregatedUserDetailsService.java:47: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : class UserDetails
>   location: class org.red5.demo.auth.AggregatedUserDetailsService
>       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

What should I do now? I'm quite new in Red5 and haven't used Java for a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend to use Eclipse as the examples are build with it. If you got that running you can still migrate your project to Netbeans.

Did you successfully set up a new Project with Red5 in Eclipse/Netbeans and build that before? 
The Tutorial requires to set up a basic project to get started. What you try to complete is actually a sample project (that might have very little use for you practically)

Actually if you followed the 3 initial points:

- Create a new red5 project
- Import project into Eclipse
- Create an application adapter

You got already your Red5 webapp. No need to follow the rest of the guide if you do not need especially this auth mechanism.

There are also a couple of demo applications with source code in their SVN. Maybe those are also a good way to get started.

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried to compile with the "ant" command in the terminal but the result is the same. There is a "build.bat" that contains this command. This is not my first project, I'm looking for some security solution thats why I tried this.

Comment: Yes but the libs you downloaded manually just do not match the libs required by the app. package org.springframework.security.core.userdetail for example simply does not exist. So you either missed some JARs or put the wrong versions into it. I can hardly tell you what you have done wrong. The sample that you are looking at is not providing any security, it is just an auth mechanism to load some users from a property file. You potentially could also secure your app by editing the red5-web.properties or load the users from a database. However first you need to set up a working Red5 webapp.

Comment: I downloaded and placed in the lib folder the following files: spring-security-acl-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar, spring-security-acl-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-config-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar, spring-security-config-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar, spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar. When I add them into Netbeans' classpath the code completion works properly. I saw the exact version requirements in the ivy.xml and in the first (ant) error output. I would like to test this example because of CRAM mechanism and want to implement it in my project.

Comment: You fixed the project setup, however the build mechanism I guess copies those JARs either in WEB-INF/lib or somewhere else in the webapp's classpath. Maybe you try adding those apps to your app's WEB-INF/lib/ dir and restart Red5.

Comment: However it might happen that you have to add them to the servers lib where all the spring related JARs are located.

Comment: I copied those JARs to the Red5's main lib folder and than I had only 1 error. So I downloaded the whole Spring framework to the main lib and it's working now! Thanks!:)